# I need return string when the age typed was different of a number

Tags: java, string, function, int

1. Hi, I attached my solution about yours problems, I comment diferents parts about code. There are two functions where a signal if is a numérica data or category of age. &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.print("Type your age: ");

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   //Save var String
       String ageStr = sc.nextLine();

       String notify="Not an age.";
       //Evaluate the age if we typify a number.
           if (isNumeric(ageStr)==true) {
               int age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
               notify = myAge(age);
           }

       //Notification about your Age
           System.out.println(notify);
   }
   //Method about Age
   public static String myAge(int age) {

       if (age >= 18) {
           return "Over 18 or equals 18";
       }
       else if (age == 0) {
           return "0 age?";
       }
       else if (age <= 18) {
           return "Under 18";
       }
       return null;
   }
   //Method is numeric?
   public static boolean isNumeric(final String str) {

       if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
           return false;
       }

       for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
           if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
               return false;
           }
       }

       return true;

   }
   ```

   }

I hope that can I help you

Regards

---

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program doesn't work.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show any attempt to use `String age2 = Integer.toString(age)`, which makes it difficult for us to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Use camel case for methods in Java.

Comment: Your problem is not that you can't convert an int to String, your problem is that you don't properly check the input prior reading it as int. I'll link you a question which tells you how to do that.

Comment: If i just return "Not an age" this happens: Type your age: dsadsa
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Prova.Age.AgeFunction(Age.java:14)
 at Prova.Test.main(Test.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `nextInt` throws exceptions. You can handle them with `try`/`catch`. The docs tell you which exceptions `nextInt` throws and why. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you'll currently get an `InputMismatchException`. You could simply catch this and return your desired value.

[Doc for Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) linked by [arcadeblast77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4612071/arcadeblast77)

```
public class Age {

    public String AgeFunction() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// User type your age
        try {
            System.out.print("Type your age: ");
            int age = sc.nextInt();

            if (age >= 18) {
                return "Over 18 or equals 18";
            }

            else if (age == 0) {
                return "0 age?";
            }

            else if (age <= 18) {
                return "Under 18";
            }

    // If what was typped be different int, return string


        } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
            return "Not an age.";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks DerMolly, and everyone, now its working correctly!